# После авторизации по ssh через терминал ничего не происходит

Tags: linux, сервер, ssh, shell, консоль

Вводные:
Доступ по ssh настроен, все ключи уже на сервере, подключиться по sftp через ssh-ключи удается - все работает. В данный момент требуется подключиться к серверу через терминал для выполнения определенных команд

Текущая ситуация:

1. Подключаюсь через терминал командой `ssh login_name@server.address`
2. Отображается приветственный motd

   ```
   he programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
   the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
   individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

   Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
   permitted by applicable law.
   Last login: Thu Nov 15 10:33:32 2018 from 109.194.155.9

   The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
   the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
   individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

   Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
   permitted by applicable law.
   ```

   3. Далее ничего не происходит, просто пустые строки в консоли. Ввод команд ничего не дает. Через несколько секунд соединение закрывается
      [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите куда смотреть, спасибо!

Логи с дебагом:

```
peresada@peresada-HP-ProDesk-400-G3-DM:~$ ssh -vvv peresada_ea@{запрашиваемый хост}
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/peresada/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/peresada/.ssh/config line 6: Applying options for *.ertelecom.ru
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "{запрашиваемый хост}" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to {запрашиваемый хост} [109.194.148.12] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/peresada/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/peresada/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/peresada/.ssh/peresada type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/peresada/.ssh/peresada-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/peresada/.ssh/peresada_ea type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/peresada/.ssh/peresada_ea-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to {запрашиваемый хост}:22 as 'peresada_ea'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/peresada/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/peresada/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/peresada/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/peresada/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 3 keys from {запрашиваемый хост}
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:qJ6MQ1g46xSAbDSs7yiNC7PMgfH6/VZ9QGmxtyvHA1M
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/peresada/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/peresada/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/peresada/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/peresada/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 3 keys from {запрашиваемый хост}
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/peresada/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/peresada/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 109.194.148.12
debug1: Host '{запрашиваемый хост}' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/peresada/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /home/peresada/.ssh/peresada (0x56093143f630), explicit, agent
debug2: key: /home/peresada/.ssh/id_rsa (0x56093143e040), explicit, agent
debug2: key: /home/peresada/.ssh/peresada_ea (0x56093143e090), explicit, agent
debug2: key: @persada.ea (0x5609314421c0), agent
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:w9jxKjTOjJtZBfzsZot9wD/dzCkArf5f0XYlXSqa3JQ /home/peresada/.ssh/peresada
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:2jeLb/VWD2k4eLajrKL1tLgtQkYczuCKQ0cmmDIlxj0 /home/peresada/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:2jeLb/VWD2k4eLajrKL1tLgtQkYczuCKQ0cmmDIlxj0
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:2jeLb/VWD2k4eLajrKL1tLgtQkYczuCKQ0cmmDIlxj0
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to {запрашиваемый хост} ([109.194.148.12]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env CLUTTER_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env LESSCLOSE
debug3: Ignored env XDG_MENU_PREFIX
debug1: Sending env LANG = ru_RU.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE
debug3: Ignored env COLORTERM
debug3: Ignored env USERNAME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_VTNR
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env DESKTOP_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env QT4_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env TEXTDOMAINDIR
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env TEXTDOMAIN
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AGENT_PID
debug3: Ignored env QT_ACCESSIBILITY
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_TYPE
debug3: Ignored env XDG_DATA_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT
debug3: Ignored env GTK_MODULES
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWPATH
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env VTE_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env QT_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env XMODIFIERS
debug3: Ignored env IM_CONFIG_PHASE
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env GPG_AGENT_INFO
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SEAT
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env GDMSESSION
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env XAUTHORITY
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CONFIG_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS
debug3: Ignored env SESSION_MANAGER
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env GTK_IM_MODULE
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Thu Nov 15 10:33:32 2018 from 109.194.155.9

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.





debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)

debug3: send packet: type 1
Connection to {запрашиваемый хост} closed.
Transferred: sent 3412, received 2624 bytes, in 4.4 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 768.7, received 591.2
debug1: Exit status 11
```

Comment: Надо смотреть конфиги на стороне сервера. Какой у вас шелл в /etc/passwd и не включены ли вы в специальную группу ssh (или прописаны в его конфигаях явно), которой разрешен только доступ к sftp. Да, у sshd есть такая настройка и подозреваю что в вашем случае именно она и включена

Comment: @Mike доступа к этим данным у меня нет, но я передал эту информацию админам, спасибо за подсказку

Comment: приложите вывод команды `$ ssh login_name@server.address env`